Conditional rendering not working for roles but working for auth
I wrote this code in my navigation component.  Although having the right return of my API, the elements are not visible.  The thing I really find confusing is that the isAuth is working properly for changing Login and Logout and showing the Homepage.
// Import Basics
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ColorSwitch } from './ColorSwitch';

// Import Services
import authService from '../../services/auth.service';

export const Navigation: React.FC = () => {
  const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isRole, setIsRole] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    authService.checkAuth()
      .then(data => setIsAuth((data as { isAuthenticated: boolean }).isAuthenticated));
    authService.checkRole()
      .then(data => setIsRole(data as string));
  }, []);


Above you can see how I handle the data.
Below you can see how it is put into my TSX.
  return (
    <div className="navbar bg-hff_purple">
      <div className="flex-1">
        <a href={isAuth ? "/" : "/login"} className="btn btn-ghost text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue text-xl">Production HFF</a>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-none">
        <ul className="menu menu-horizontal px-1">
          {isAuth ? <li><a href="/" className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Home</a></li> : null}
          {(isRole === 'staff' || isRole === 'horeca') ? (
            <li>
              <details>
                <summary>Horeca</summary>
                <ul className="bg-hff_purple rounded-t-none p-2">
                  <li><a href='/horeca' className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Horeca Dashboard</a></li>
                  <li><a href='/horeca-form' className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Horeca Form</a></li>
                  {isRole === 'staff' ? <li><a href='/horeca-admin' className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Horeca Admin</a></li> : null}
                </ul>
              </details>
            </li>) : null}
          {isRole === 'staff' ? (
            <li>
              <details>
                <summary>Volunteers</summary>
                <ul className="bg-hff_purple rounded-t-none p-2">
                  <li><a href='/volunteers' className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Volunteer Dashboard</a></li>
                  <li><a href='/volunteer-admin' className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Volunteer Admin</a></li>
                </ul>
              </details>
            </li>) : null}
          {isAuth ? <li><a href="/logout" className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Logout</a></li> : <li><a href="/login" className='text-white hover:text-hff_light_blue'>Login</a></li>}
          <li>
            <ColorSwitch />
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

This is how I access the API
const checkRole = async () => {
  const response = await axiosInstance.get(`/auth/userinfo/role/`);
  return response.data;
};

How do I fix that my elements that are hidden for unauthorised users become visible when having the right role.
Sorry for the messy code, as I am a beginner I guess.
